# How Can I Format A HTML Page I'm Outputting From Java?

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I am messing around with a small project this weekend, and part of it I want to take the results of my output that would normally go to my console and output them to an HTML file.

```
     File file = new File("C:/Users/Files/Desktop/TestTest/Test22.html");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.out.println("The Total of this output is" + totalAmt);
    System.out.println("Average amount is " + average);
```

Now both lines print out just fine. But they print out on one line, nearly run together, and just don't look appealing in the slightest. Is there anything I can do in Eclipse to format the html page before I print my values to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things. The first is code the html formatting into your program to be written out. In other words, something like inserting

```
System.out.println("<br />");
```

between your print statments.

The other thing you could do is write a formatted html page and read it from memory as a long string, and then only overwrite the things you want to, perhaps by searching for specific tags and editing the text between them. When you are done you can save the file back.

If all you need is a little bit of simple formatting, the first method will be better. If the page you want is quite complex, the second is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

My team did something similar to what you're doing but in PHP. There wasn't anything specific to the *IDE* that made formatting it easier. We had to include the new line characters/tabs/etc. in the actual string itself. Then, when the HTML was generated, it came out looking really nice.

I would suggest doing the same thing here. A line break won't make the HTML look any better. It will just take jumbled code and make it two blocks of jumbled code.